# Vue Getter & Setter instead of the actual values in backend response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and I'm struggling to understand why my problem is happening.

When I make a call to my backend to retrieve some data the response is as follows:

```
id: Getter & Setter
name: Getter & Setter
season: Getter & Setter
number: Getter & Setter
```

Within Vue, if I change data to be an object instead of a function, I get the values I expect.

```
id:10897
name:"Minimum Viable Product"
season:1
number:1
```

From reading Vue's documentation I know data should be a function, however I don't see why it affects the data I am getting?

I retrieve the data like so:

```
methods: {
     async episodes() {
      const response = await EpisodesService.getAllEpisodes()
      console.log(response)
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the backend response to data?

Comment: I put the code in the main question to format it, I can see the data correctly in Postman and within the network tab of my browser, but not within Vue itself

Comment: So you are setting it to a `const` and not `data` object?

Comment: yes I set the `const` response to equal the response, and then set a variable on data called allEpisodes to store part of the response.

`this.allEpisodes = response.data.allEpisodes;`

Comment: hmm I've 'fixed' it. It seems firefox returns the response with `Getter & Setter` instead of the values. So it is working, but the values are returned strangely and that was throwing me off

Comment: How did u fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

you can change data to be an object instead of a function, but not recommend. If Vue didn’t have this rule, clicking on one component would affect the data of all other instances.

Answer (score -1):

Use the JSON stringify function:

```
JSON.stringify(response.data.allEpisodes)
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.