# Using commit in actions with promises returns 'Getters & Setters'

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, promise, action, vuex

I'm using Vuex's 'actions' to fetch from my database via an API.

It works well and I have a `console.log(jsonResponse)` which shows the correct data.

However, when I add `commit('updateQuestions', jsonResponse)` to the picture, the return values for all of the fields are `"Setters & Getters"`

#### store.js:

```
mutations: {
    updateQuestionsInit: (state, payload) => {
        state.questions.init = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    onInit: async ({commit}) => {
        try {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/mongo/initialforms')

            if (response.ok) {
                let jsonResponse = await response.json()
                console.log(jsonResponse)
                // Omitting the below line means it works.
                commit('updateQuestionsInit', jsonResponse)
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('ERROR', error)
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

#### Expected Results

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        type: "dropdown",
        value: "sku",
    }, ...
]
```

#### Actual Results

```
[
    {
        id: Getter & Setter,
        type: Getter & Setter
        value: Getter & Setter,
        … 
    }, ...

]
```

*Why does this happen and how would it be rectified?*

Comment: What does "the return values for all of the fields are "Setters & Getters"" mean?  Where are you looking at the results?  Is this from the `console.log(jsonResponse)` line of code?

Comment: Does the `commit()` function modify the `jsonResponse` object it is passed?  If so, then this is probably an issue with `console.log(jsonResponse)` not actually logging the object until after `commit()` has already modified it.  You can test this theory by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse))` instead.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just tried your troubleshooting. `JSON.stringify()` passes it through as intended. Once it gets to the mutation, I used `JSON.parse()` to change it back and it still happened.

These properties of `Setters & Getters` are now in my state, instead of actual values

Comment: Well, that's apparently because `commit()` is modifying your object.  Go look at that code, not this code.  That's where it's getting modified.  Nothing else we can suggest based on the code you've shown so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Firefox? Others experienced similar issues but for them it seemed to work on chrome. Apparently, Firefox *shows* "Setters & Getters" in the console but the underlying values are correct.

**-> Switch to Chrome and see if the issue remains.**

---

**References**

[Vue Getter & Setter instead of the actual values in backend response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852880/vue-getter-setter-instead-of-the-actual-values-in-backend-response)

https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/webextension-apis-made-as-getter-setter-lazily-evaluating-to-functions-beware-of-mocking-for-unit-tests/30849

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm that the values underlying are correct. I didn't have the front set up so I couldn't check to see it was being passed through. Firefox console as deceived me!