# How to copy an array of objects from created function to data in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, vue.js

I have an array of objects in my created hook called tempArray that is created when firebase returns data from firestore. The array should look kind of like this:

```
[{name: "some value", description: "some value", imageSrc: "some value"}, {name: "some value", description: "some value", imageSrc: "some value"} ...]
```

The problem occurs when I try to copy this array in to an empty array called orgArray in my data function. The keys are copied properly but the values are all replaced by "Getter & Setter." So the resulting array looks like this:

```
[{name: "Getter & Setter", description: "Getter & Setter", imageSrc: "Getter & Setter"...]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<script>
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
require("firebase/firestore");



export default {
  components: {
    Navigation
  },
  data: function(){
    return{
      user: true,
      orgArray: []
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    var self = this;
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var tempArray = [];

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if(user){
         self.$nextTick(function(){
          self.user = 'true';
        })
      }
    })

    db.collection("organizations").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        tempArray.push(doc.data())
        //console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
    self.orgArray = tempArray;
    console.log(self.orgArray)
});


  }
}
</script>
```

I've tried just populating orgArray directly from the forEach function instead of populating tempArray and the copying the contents. I've tried mapping the two arrays, looping through the objects and populating the second array one by one, and more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be a case of asynchronous nature of javascript. Does the console.log for the tempArray work within the `forEach` loop?

Comment: Yes, the console log inside the `forEach` loop works fine. I also tried logging the value of tempArray where my above code logs self.orgArray and it outputs the proper array. So the array is properly populated before the attempt to copy it. I also replaced `tempArray.push(doc.data())` with `self.orgArray.push(doc.data())` which should populate that array the same way it populates tempArray.  For some reason the keys are copied just fine but the values never work. I can also copy the array around within the created block perfectly fine. I just can't copy it out of that block.

Comment: what if you declare `self.orgArray = []` outside the block and just push similar to `tempArray.push(doc.data())` in the forEach loop? Also does the `console.log(tempArray)` below the `console.log(self.orgArray)` work?

Comment: All the console log statements work fine. Like I mentioned in my last comment I did try pushing directly to orgArray. The result is the same. Within the created block I can name any arrays and copy from one to another just fine. The key problem is copying an array from inside the created block to an array inside the data function.

Comment: Check this thread out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852880/vue-getter-setter-instead-of-the-actual-values-in-backend-response See if this helps?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think this is heading in the right direction.  So apparently when I try to look at the entire array I get "Getter & Setter" as the values for all keys. When I try to access a single object like this `orgArray[2]` it returns [object, object]. The interesting part is that when I do this: `orgArray[2].name` it returns the proper value. So as long as I reference specific keys then I get the correct values. So now the question is how do I use the array as a whole and how do I access the objects within the array as whole objects?

Comment: Try using it as is. Otherwise you could use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` for a deep copy? See here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/#8-json-parse-and-json-stringify-deep-copy-

Comment: Ok, I've tried making a deep copy and that also does not work. As long as I only access the key value pairs one by one then I can use the array. However, I cannot use the array to access the objects as a whole. So, when I attempt to access orgArray[1] for example, the value that is returned is [object, object] and not {name: "some value", description: "some value", imageSrc: "some value"} etc